# PHP Removing Windows ^M Character

Tags: php, linux, sanitize

I have a CSV I am downloading from a source I'm not in control of and the end of each line is a

```
^M
```

character when printed to a bash terminal. How can I sanitize this input programmatically in PHP?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you're seeing is a Windows control character.  To get rid of this in PHP, what you need to do is 
    `$file = str_ireplace("\x0D", "", $file)` 
this will work whether hexadecimal is lowercase or uppercase.

Answer (score 5):

You can also ask PHP to auto detect any weird line endings by just adding in this line before reading the CSV file and you won't be required to do anything else.

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
```

Comment: Valid approach, but did not work for me, which is a bit weird. I ended up replacing win with linux chars: preg_replace('~\r\n?~', "\n", $string);

Comment: Ok, I think it might be possible you have a different OS to mine. I am using Mac, so it might not be working on all OS. It is weird as you said.

Answer (score 4):

`^M` is a [carriage return](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/digraph.html#digraph-table), you should be able to remove it with:

```
$string = str_replace( "\r", "", $string);
```